# is it necessary for a function to be defined everywhere in it's domain to be onto or one-to-one mapping?

Tags: functions

[this is question. I want to know about iv.] I want to know that without being defined everywhere ,can a  mapping be onto and one-to-one?
In iv - D has four elements and B has three elements, while in question only three elements are used. So it cannot be function as per definition. Then how it will onto or one to one without function? Is it possible?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfArD.png)

Comment: The answer already posted below is not addressing your question. A function is defined everywhere on its domain *by definition*. This is not about being one-to-one or onto, but is about the very meaning of a function. For example, a function defined only on positive numbers can’t be called a function on all real numbers that just is not defined on numbers less than or equal to $0$. When you say a function has domain $A$, then it is defined on *all* of $A$.

Comment: I think the comment of @KCd is spot on. In particular, in the image you provide, the function $f_4$ is not a function from $D$ to $B$ at all!

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of terminology and notation. In Set  Theory a function $is$ its graph, and when we say "$f$ is a function from $A$ to $B\,$", or write $f: A\to B$ we mean that $f\subseteq A\times B$ and $\forall a\in A\,\,\exists! \,b\in B\,(\,(a,b)\in f)$... (where "$\exists!$" means "there exists exactly one"). And $A$ is called the domain of $f$.

A source of confusion is that strict adherence to this definition is sometimes tedious or inconvenient. E.g. suppose $f:\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ where $f(x)= e^{-1/|x|},\,$ and suppose you  say that we extend $f$ to all of $\Bbb R$ by letting $f(0)=0$. No one will find fault with this. But technically there is no such thing as $f(0)$. A pedantic adherence to the def'n would require you to say "Let $g=f\cup \{(0,0)\}.\,$" Just remember that there are no exceptions to the def'n, but that sometimes it is easier to act as  if there were.

Answer (score 0):

One- one and onto is merely a type of function . So yes the function needs to be defined everywhere in it's domain for it to be one - one or onto. The question you are referring to  will therefore will be neither defined in domain nor one- one or onto